# make counter in ASP.NET & C#

Tags: asp.net

i want to make counter in ASP but i give an error . "use of unassigned local variable 'c'  " i change the c & t to the uint but again i give this error . the counter Code located at the bottom of codes.

```
         string strQuery = "INSERT INTO [SingleSeatTable](SeatNumber,TableName,EventCode,Reserved,customer_id)" + "VALUES(@SeatNumber,@TableName,@EventCode,@Reserved,@customer_id)";

        SqlConnection connection = DBConnection.getConnection();
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        cmd.CommandText = strQuery;

        string cis = Session["customerID"].ToString();
        /******query No.1********/
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SeatNumber", seatnumber);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@TableName", seatname);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EventCode", "100");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Reserve", "1");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Reserved", "1");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@customer_id", cis);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();

        uint t;
        uint c;
        c++;
        t = c;

        if (t >= 2)
        {
            Messages myMsg = new Messages(); // ایجاد نمونه از کلاس
            myMsg.CreateMessageAlert("ظرفیت رزرو شما پر شده است . شما نمی توانید بیش از دو صندلی انتخاب نمایید");
        }

        else { 
        Response.Redirect("ReservationSucces.aspx");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign a value to c first otherwise it doesn't know what to increment:

```
uint c=0;
```